# Uploading a file via FtpWebRequest The remote server returned an error 227 entering passive mode

Tags: vb.net, upload, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I'm reading data from my database and reformatting it into a comma delimited CSV file which I need to upload to an FTP server.

This procedure reads in the Byte array of the string that contains the data in the comma delimited format and uploads it to the server:

```
Private Sub uploadToServer(ByVal data() As Byte, ByVal filename As String)
    Try
        Dim ftpr As FtpWebRequest = _
            DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(String.Format("ftp://ftp.this.com/{0}", filename)), FtpWebRequest)
        ftpr.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("thisUser", "somePassword0rOther")
        ftpr.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

        Using stream As Stream = ftpr.GetRequestStream()
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        el.WriteEntry(String.Format("Error uploading file: {1}", vbNewLine & ex.Message))
    End Try
End Sub
```

At least, that's what it's supposed to do... and what it did yesterday. Now though, I keep getting this returned in the Exception:

> The remote server returned an error: 227 Entering Passive Mode

I've been getting the same error while attempting to connect to the same server with FileZilla which makes me think that the problem is on the server.

I don't intend to troubleshoot server issues here, but what I do need is confirmation that there's nothing wrong with this code. Then I can go to serverfault and query about any possible server issues there.

So... Is there anything wrong with this code?

**EDIT**
Testing other ways of accessing the FTP I've discovered:

- Accessing the FTP via RDP into the server itself (Windows Server 2008 R2) works
- FileZilla returns `Connection timed out. Failed to retrieve directory listing`
- Connecting via Windows Explorer returns `An error occurred opening that folder on the FTP Server. Make sure you have permission to access that folder. Details: The operation timed out`. The same happens when anyone in the office makes an attempt to access the server via FTP.

I'm pretty sure this is also what's happening in my application.

Answer (score 0):

According to [NCFtp's Documentation](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftpd/doc/misc/ftp_and_firewalls.html), this is the appropriate response when requesting the server to enter passive mode. I think that you may be interpreting the response as an error when you should not be.

Also, according to [Wikipedia's FTP return code entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes), all responses that begin with 2xx are positive responses; they indicate success. Specifically, `227` indicates success transition to passive mode.

Comment: That's what I thought, but if 227 is good news, what's causing the Exception?

Comment: What's outputting the string: `The remote server returned an error`. I don't see that anywhere in your code. Where does the code jump into the exception? Perhaps that message has nothing to do with what's really causing the exception.

Comment: the last line to execute before the Catch block gets hit is `stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)`. Basically, attempting to write the file to the server. This worked on Monday though...

Comment: As you indicated in your post, it feels like a server problem. Can you have someone else try hitting the server with a different FTP client, and see if they experience the same error? Also - have you changed any of the code since it previously worked?

Comment: I've updated the question with some test results. Also, that particular procedure hasn't changed since I wrote it on Monday (when it worked)

Comment: If it works from localhost, it could be a firewall issue. Try temporarily disabling Windows Firewall, if it's enabled?

Comment: Okay, I set it up to use a different server for the FTP and it works, so looks like it's a server issue... Your answer was very helpful though in determining what steps to follow next

Comment: Were you able to toggle the firewall temporarily to see if that made any difference?

Answer (score 0):

**227 Entering Passive Mode is a valid response to an FTP PASV command.  I'm not sure why we would be throwing this as an exception.** Possibly your firewall.

Also you have not constructed your FTP correctly check out my FTP class: Its pretty straight forward.

```
Public Class FTP
        '-------------------------[BroCode]--------------------------
        '----------------------------FTP-----------------------------
        Private _credentials As System.Net.NetworkCredential
        Sub New(ByVal _FTPUser As String, ByVal _FTPPass As String)
            setCredentials(_FTPUser, _FTPPass)
        End Sub
        Public Sub UploadFile(ByVal _FileName As String, ByVal _UploadPath As String)
            Dim _FileInfo As New System.IO.FileInfo(_FileName)
            Dim _FtpWebRequest As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = CType(System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create(New Uri(_UploadPath)), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
            _FtpWebRequest.Credentials = _credentials
            _FtpWebRequest.KeepAlive = False
            _FtpWebRequest.Timeout = 20000
            _FtpWebRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
            _FtpWebRequest.UseBinary = True
            _FtpWebRequest.ContentLength = _FileInfo.Length
            Dim buffLength As Integer = 2048
            Dim buff(buffLength - 1) As Byte
            Dim _FileStream As System.IO.FileStream = _FileInfo.OpenRead()
            Try
                Dim _Stream As System.IO.Stream = _FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
                Dim contentLen As Integer = _FileStream.Read(buff, 0, buffLength)
                Do While contentLen <> 0
                    _Stream.Write(buff, 0, contentLen)
                    contentLen = _FileStream.Read(buff, 0, buffLength)
                Loop
                _Stream.Close()
                _Stream.Dispose()
                _FileStream.Close()
                _FileStream.Dispose()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Upload Error: ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
        End Sub
        Public Sub DownloadFile(ByVal _FileName As String, ByVal _ftpDownloadPath As String)
            Try
                Dim _request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(_ftpDownloadPath)
                _request.KeepAlive = False
                _request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
                _request.Credentials = _credentials
                Dim _response As System.Net.FtpWebResponse = _request.GetResponse()
                Dim responseStream As System.IO.Stream = _response.GetResponseStream()
                Dim fs As New System.IO.FileStream(_FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create)
                responseStream.CopyTo(fs)
                responseStream.Close()
                _response.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Download Error: ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
        End Sub
        Public Function GetDirectory(ByVal _ftpPath As String) As List(Of String)
            Dim ret As New List(Of String)
            Try
                Dim _request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(_ftpPath)
                _request.KeepAlive = False
                _request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails
                _request.Credentials = _credentials
                Dim _response As System.Net.FtpWebResponse = _request.GetResponse()
                Dim responseStream As System.IO.Stream = _response.GetResponseStream()
                Dim _reader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream)
                Dim FileData As String = _reader.ReadToEnd
                Dim Lines() As String = FileData.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                For Each l As String In Lines
                    ret.Add(l)
                Next
                _reader.Close()
                _response.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Directory Fetch Error: ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
            Return ret
        End Function

        Private Sub setCredentials(ByVal _FTPUser As String, ByVal _FTPPass As String)
            _credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(_FTPUser, _FTPPass)
        End Sub
    End Class
```

To initialize:

```
Dim ftp As New FORM.FTP("username", "password")

ftp.UploadFile("c:\file.jpeg", "ftp://domain/file.jpeg")

ftp.DownloadFile("c:\file.jpeg", "ftp://ftp://domain/file.jpeg")

Dim directory As List(Of String) = ftp.GetDirectory("ftp://ftp.domain.net/")
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        For Each item As String In directory
            ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
        Next
```